# Django parent template has to act as a child template to itself

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm just beginning to use Django's template extending feature, and I've hit a bit of a problem.
So I have here two html templates, one is the main section page, the other is a specific 'post' page

**Main Section Page**

```
{% if latest_post_list %}
    {% for post in latest_post_list %}
        <a href = "{% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}"><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></a>  
        <h2>{{post.author}}</h2>
        <h2>{{post.pub_date}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
        {% if post.video_set.all.exists %}
            <h3>Videos</h3>
        {% endif %}
        {% for video in post.video_set.all %}
            <a href = "{{video.url}}"><h4>Here is a video</h4></a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if post.link_set.all.exists %}
            <h3>Links</h3>
        {% endif %}
        {% for link in post.link_set.all %}
            <a href = "{{link.url}}">{{link.name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>no recent posts made</p>
{% endif %}
```

**Post Page**

```
<h1>{{post}}</h1>
<h2>{{post.author}}</h2>
<h2>{{post.pub_date}}</h2>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
{% if post.video_set.all.exists %}
            <h3>Videos</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for video in post.video_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{video.url}}"><h4>Here is a video</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
{% if post.link_set.all.exists %}
    <h3>Links</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for link in post.link_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{link.url}}">{{link.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is have the following code (which is the same for both pages) get extended:

```
{% if post.video_set.all.exists %}
            <h3>Videos</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for video in post.video_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{video.url}}"><h4>Here is a video</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
{% if post.link_set.all.exists %}
    <h3>Links</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for link in post.link_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{link.url}}">{{link.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

To my understanding of how Django inheritance works, I would make this code the parent template and make the unique portions of the Main Section Page/Post Page child templates. The problem arises in the Main Section page, where I cannot make it easily pluggable into the 'parent template.' The entire 'parent template' section of the Main Section page is enveloped in an additional `{% for %}{% endfor %}` loop, meaning code from the parent template is in the (eventual) `{% block %}`child template, which is itself meant to be plugged back into the parent template. (This is akin to inception)

Hence my conundrum is that the parent template must act as a child template to itself, which is impossible. I therefore have two questions:

1. How could I effectively re-model the Main Section Page to make it pluggable? If possible, may I have an example?
2. Is this situation ideal for inheritance, or is it more strategic to let the code overlap stand?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your approach does just not fit to your problem.
Basically, you have a section of code that you want to reuse. This section requires some input - the variable `post`.

Your snippet may even be extended, since everything except the title seems to be the same - you could add the following as well:

```
    <h2>{{post.author}}</h2>
    <h2>{{post.pub_date}}</h2>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
```

You have several possibilities now.
I will tell you about inclusion and templatetags - templatetags being my favourite for this one.

### Inclusion

You could include that part of your template into the "normal" template - basically the opposite of the Template extension you wanted to do in the first place (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

Post this into your new included template (`yourapp/included.html` for simplicity sake):

```
<h2>{{post.author}}</h2>
<h2>{{post.pub_date}}</h2>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
{% if post.video_set.all.exists %}
            <h3>Videos</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for video in post.video_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{video.url}}"><h4>Here is a video</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
{% if post.link_set.all.exists %}
    <h3>Links</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for link in post.link_set.all %}
    <a href = "{{link.url}}">{{link.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then include it in your other templates like this:

```
{% include "yourapp/included.html" %}
```

### Templatetags

Django allows you to write your own templatetags. This means that instead of rendering your blog entry manually, you could bass it to a tag and let the tag do the rest. This usually allows for an easy tempalte reading flow and thus is my favourite solution. You could even add additional options to it (e.g. a switch for linking the title in order to incorporate that one as well) or do multiple tags.

The initial setup of tempaltetags is a little bit more complicated but absolutely worth it on the long run. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/ for more details.

I will show you a solution with one templatetag for your problem, especially for the video and link lists, I would recommend you to split it into several tags later (same method but more tags):

1. In your app folder, create a module "templatetags" (do not forget the **init**.py file)
2. In this templatetags folder, create a new module. the module name is the name of the templatetag library you will be loading later. Example: `yourapp_tags.py`
3. Register an inclusion tag and pass the variable through it to the template (you are very welcome to be a little bit more creative on the documentation):

   ```
   from django import template
   register = template.Library()
   @register.inclusion_tag('templatetags/yourapp/post.html')
   def render_post(post):
       """
       Rendering a Post into the template
       :param post: The blog post that should be rendered
       :return: Rendered blog post
       :template: templatetags/yourapp/post.html
       """
       return {
           "post": post,
       }
   ```
4. Now create the template path and template in your apps template directory (I usually separate tempaltetag tempaltes from the normal ones):

   ```
   <h2>{{post.author}}</h2>
   <h2>{{post.pub_date}}</h2>
   <p>{{post.body}}</p>
   {% if post.video_set.all.exists %}
               <h3>Videos</h3>
   {% endif %}
   {% for video in post.video_set.all %}
       <a href = "{{video.url}}"><h4>Here is a video</h4></a>
   {% endfor %}
   {% if post.link_set.all.exists %}
       <h3>Links</h3>
   {% endif %}
   {% for link in post.link_set.all %}
       <a href = "{{link.url}}">{{link.name}}</a>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   5. In your templates, now import the template tag library and use the new template tag to render your post:

#### Main section page

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}
{% if latest_post_list %}
    {% for post in latest_post_list %}
        <a href = "{% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}"><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></a> 
        {% render_post post %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>no recent posts made</p>
{% endif %}
```

#### Post page

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}
<h1>{{post}}</h1>
{% render_post post %}
```

This definitely looks more complicated. But by just creating partial templates in the template tags and by splitting up this example tag into 3 different tags, you could render the post content, videos and links separately wherever you like, render the post without videos and links in the list, ... all with just writing the templatetag. Using templatetags, the code is easily reusable. I often use them for rendering content in my templates or for creating widgets that I can include in the main page or a sidebar.

### For completeness of the answer

To be complete, I would like to answer to your questions directly as well:

> How could I effectively re-model the Main Section Page to make it
>   pluggable? If possible, may I have an example?

In my experience, it is best to define a base template that does only contain the basic page layout and block definitions. All other templates extend this base template and overwrite just the blocks they need. You may extend templates multiple times, if you just want to modify part of a more specialized page, for example. You may even define new blocks in the templates extending the base template and overwrite them in the next template extending the template that defined the new blocks. But be careful, those "inheritance hierarchies" confuse you relatively fast and are hard to maintain. Use them, but use them with caution.

> Is this situation ideal for inheritance, or is it more strategic to let the code overlap stand?

Neither. As mentioned above, this is perfect for either including a sub-template or - in my eyes better - creating your own template tags. You are absolutely right, code overlap is never a good thing to have. Avoid that at all costs (my personal opinion). Inheritance on the other hand  is not as dynamic as you are hoping for. For templates, inheritance is there to inherit structures, not to repeatedly parse the same information. That is what inclusion (templatetags are IMHO also a more flexible way of inclusion with additional properties) is for.

Long post but hopefully, it helped you with your problem :-)